# WPF edit textblock in page from another page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am using http://mui.codeplex.com/ for a project, and now I need to edit some elements in e.g. page1.xaml with the code of page2.xaml.cs. Tried many searches but didn't manage to get it working.

Read something about PropertyChanged but didn't do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When passing values from one window to another in WPF, it is very useful to learn and read about MVVM and Data Binding. PropertyChanged **DOES** the trick.

Here are some links that may help you:

[The Basics of MVVM by Paul Sheriff](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/05/23/the-basics-of-mvvm.aspx)

[MVVM in XAML: Simple and Easy by Paul Sheriff](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV216)